# Using VBA to choose from Dropdown in HTML

Tags: html, vba

I am trying to use VBA to select from a dropdown list. The HTML code is below

```html
<select name="template" class="chzn-select stdText allow_single_deselect" 
id="template" style="width: 315px; display: none; visibility: visible;" 
onchange="newDoc.doAfterTemplateNew('templateRow',this);" size="3" 
data-automation-id="authorTemplateDropdown" data-placeholder="Choose template...">
   <option></option>
   <option value="1">1. Company_Comment (CC)</option>
   <option value="3">1. Company_Flash (CF)</option>
   <option value="79">1. Company_Report (CR)</option>
   <option value="21">2. Sector_Comment (SC)</option>
```

Right now I am trying to use:

```
.document.querySelector("Select[name=template] option[value=1]").Selected = True
```

However, I am getting error 8070000c. Thank you for the help!

Comment: "an error" is not a very useful description of what happens when you run your code

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry - error 8070000c

Comment: What's the text of the message?

Comment: @TimWilliams Runtime Error '-2140143604(8070000c). Could not complete due to error 8070000c.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the rest of your code, showing how you're loading the page, up to the point where it errors.  A single line of code is a little out of context.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  Note quotes around option `value` attribute

```vb
Sub tester()
    'Added reference to Microsoft HTML Object Model
    Dim doc As New HTMLDocument, opt As Object, slct As Object
    
    doc.body.innerHTML = Range("A1").Value 'load HTML from cell for testing

    Set slct = doc.querySelector("select[name=template]")                   'select object
    Set opt = doc.querySelector("select[name=template] option[value='1']")  'option
    
    Debug.Print "before", slct.selectedIndex  ' >> -1
    opt.Selected = True
    Debug.Print "after", slct.selectedIndex   ' >> 1
    
End Sub
```

HTML in A1:

```html
<select name="template"  id="template"   size="3"  data-placeholder="Choose template...">
   <option></option>
   <option value="1">1. Company_Comment (CC)</option>
   <option value="3">1. Company_Flash (CF)</option>
   <option value="79">1. Company_Report (CR)</option>
   <option value="21">2. Sector_Comment (SC)</option>
</select>
```